# Web Admin Panel to Update React-Native App

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I recently started learning React Native to develop mobile applications. I am starting to comprehend its logic in general by making simple applications. While doing this, a question struck me.
Let's say I developed an app and published it on the Play Store. Then, I changed this application and designed an update. What should I do for users to have this update? Should I delete the old version from the Play Store and install the APK file of the current version of the application? That is the first part of my question. Now my main question is this;

Let's say I developed an application for a restaurant. The app includes simple things like the restaurant's menu and a monthly event calendar. The application needs to be updated weekly or monthly because changes may occur in the event calendar and menu. How to make a web-based admin panel where the restaurant owner can easily make these changes? I am not asking you to explain the code in any way. Just asking, how do you make a web application that allows modifications to a React Native application?

For example, a new event can be added with a template on the web panel, or new dishes can be added to the menu. What programming languages can be used to achieve this? What are the rules to follow? Could you inform me, you would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.